# Mersenne Twister vs Mersenne Twister 64 bit

Tags: c++, boost, random

Boost provides both mt19937 and mt19937_64
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.generators

Confused - do I have to use the 64 bit version (which according to the above page has far worse performance) to get good random numbers on a 64 bit platform?  Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: You're running on a 64-bit platform, but do you *need* 64-bit *randoms* ? if not (you're using them for some finite modulo, which is a mistake in-itself since you should be using the distribution classes instead), then there is no need to bring a sledgehammer to drive a thumbtack.

Comment: I'm wrapping mt19937 in distribution classes.  Does that mean it doesn't matter?

Comment: Just because you're on a 64-bit platform doesn't mean everything you do needs to be 64-bits. It's all about whether you need 64-bits in that instance. If you need 64-bits of randomness, then go ahead and use the 64-bit version. If you don't, then use the 32-bit version. Forget about whether your computer is 32- or 64-bits.

Comment: @SideshowBob If the results of mt19937 provide with appropriate random numbers for the distribution(s) you're using, there is no need to use the 64bit version. Again, you only need that if you need 64-bit random numbers (numbers from 0...9223372036854775807).

Comment: Given that boost recommends docs recommend using mt19937 by default then I can only assume that is appropriate for all its distribution classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old post, but there is a pattern of misunderstanding here where I would like to clarify a bit. Mersenne Twister internally produces integer states. It produces a sequence of random integer values (the randomness of each single bit in the integers can be evaluated). Often you convert this integer output into floating point -- hiding this fact.

If boost offers a _64 bit version this only means the internal state is an integer with 64bit and not a standard integer with 32bit. This is a non-trivial difference since the randomness of twice as many bits must be guaranteed in the 64 bit version. This is actually expensive and significantly slower. It depends a lot on your problem if you will benefit from this. It is possible -- problems due to poor quality of random number sequences are generally underestimated a lot. Mersenne Twister is anyway not an outstanding random number generator.

There are other random number generators with even 128, 256 or 512bit internal integers. I am not aware of more, but this is certainly possible.

The important note here is: this has absolutely nothing to do with your hardware system / OS being 32bit or 64bit (or anything else).